# Apache vhost wildcard not working

Tags: apache, virtualhost, wampserver, vhosts

This was working before but mysteriously doesn't work anymore. I'm trying to add a wildcard subdomain which points to the exact same folder as the main domain.

Here is my vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName leadbind.dev
    ServerAlias *.leadbind.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/leadbind/public"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/leadbind/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I saved and restarted DNS.

When I visit `leadbind.dev` it works, but when I visit `test.leadbind.dev` it does not and Chrome says `This site can't be reached`. This used to work with a different domain/subdomain wildcard I had set up as a vhost, but not this one.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently I needed to add the actual subdomain to the windows hosts file because Windows does not like wildcard subdomains.